# How to handle a redirect to a subdomain to be indexed by google?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, subdomain, google-index

I want to use my subdomain as a main page.
My main domain is empty, but the content is available on `subdomain.example.com`. And `google` neither wants to index my content nor my domain.

My `.htaccess` contains

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) https://subdomain.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

How could I redirect `google` to my subdomain?